# how to make use of rdf data of dmoz with mysql and php?

Tags: mysql, rdf, sparql, data-import, dmoz

I have searched through the web, but still not be able to get a solid answer.
My goal is to make use of [rdf data](http://www.dmoz.org/rdf.html) from dmoz, so here are 2 questions:

1. how to import the rdf into mysql? (any solid tool could be used?)
2. how to make the data queryable through SPARQL? (what component or query engine I should use)

from what I have learned I need to build the storage based on [Redland RDF libraries](http://librdf.org/), and then I can query it with SPARQL. But further reading into redland, they don't have a good document of php. Those missing gap make me confused as I am pretty new to the rdf technology.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHP then you should give [ARC 2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki) a look, it's the most popular RDF/SPARQL library for PHP and it has a MySQL based backend you can use for persistent storage and to make SPARQL queries against.